# How to get Properties from a Generic type with a Lambda expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I'm trying to filter some results from a `List<T>`, but when I try to select a property for the elements in the list, that's not possible.

This is how I call my generic method:

```
var transaction = GetTransaction(transactions, idToGet);
```

This is my generic method:

```
private TransactionDto GetTransaction<T>(List<T> transactions, int myId)
{
    var value = transactions.Where(x => x.Id == myId).FirstOrDefault();
    return value;
}
```

Since `transaction` is a generic parameter, I can't read the `Id` property, in order to compare it with the `myId` parameter.

How can I read all the properties of a generic parameter provided?

Comment: Your question isn't making much sense. Why would you write a generic method that assumes each object has an `Id` property, without providing a suitable constraint to ensure that it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the simplest way is to define some interface `IHazId` such that:

```
interface IHazId {
    int Id {get;}
}
```

and add that to your types - usually just by adding `: IHazId` to each; for example:

```
class SomeTransaction : IHazId {...} // presumably has a public int Id
```

Now add the `where T : IHazId` constraint to the generic method:

```
private TransactionDto GetTransaction<T>(List<T> transactions, int myId)
    where T : IHazId
{...}
```

and you should be set.

The other option is, unfortunately: reflection.

---

The name `IHazId` is obviously irrelevant; it could be `ITransaction`, or whatever you choose.